# What is the memoisation problem in this recursive algorithm that I cannot see?

Tags: ruby, memoization

I'm learning about data structures and algorithms via Structy.com's course, I'm trying to solve [this](https://structy.net/problems/sum-possible) problem, given a target sum and an array of numbers, can any sum of any combination of the numbers in the array match the target sum. I've written the function with memoisation but it still seems to be taking a long time on the larger trees, suggesting that the calculations either aren't being memoised or the memo'd results aren't being looked up as I'm intending. I've looked at and rewritten this so many times and just can't see where I'm going wrong. Can another pair of eyeballs see what's going wrong here.

**Method:**

```
def can_sum(target, numbers, memo = {})
  return true if target == 0
  return false if target < 0
  return memo[target] if memo[target]

  numbers.each do |n|
    remainder = target - n
    if can_sum(remainder, numbers, memo) == true
      memo[target] = true
      return true
    end
  end
  
  memo[target] = false
  return false
end
```

**Example passing cases**

```
  it "returns true when sum to target is possible from given no's" do
   result = can_sum(7, [2, 3])
   expect(result).to be(true)
  end
  
  it "returns true when sum to target is possible from given no's" do
   result = can_sum(7, [5, 3, 4, 7])
   expect(result).to be(true)
  end
```

**Example test cases taking too long**

```
  it "returns false when sum to target is impossible from given no's" do
   result = can_sum(2017, [4, 2, 10])
   expect(result).to be(false)
  end
  
  it "returns false when sum to target is impossible from given no's" do
   result = can_sum(300, [7, 14])
   expect(result).to be(false)
  end
```

Comment: Hints: 1) The memorization (`memo[target] = true`) is written after the recursive call. Which means a number of calls will not benefit from it. 2) `return memo[target] if memo[target]` will not return `false` when it was set to `memo[target] = false`. `return memo[target] if memo.key?(target)` would work with `false` was memorized.

Comment: And I suggest reading about [the Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). It is very similar to your problem, and it is NP-complete. Which might explain why it takes so long and is hard to optimize.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann, both points noted and point 2 showed me that my memorised key:value wasn't being used with your suggested `return memo[target] if memo.key?(target)` solving the problem as well as imo being more readable. And will get on to reading about Knapsack problem, v interesting, thanks for pointing me in towards this .

Comment: `can_sum(2017, [4, 2, 10])`may be "taking too long" because all possible repeated combinations must be enumerated before it can be concluded that there is no solution (`2017` is odd but no element of the array is odd). The number of such combinations, if brute force were applied, is approximately `(2017/4)*(2017/2)*(2017/10) #=> 102,114,432`.